SerialPort Class .Write method unreliable (not writing and not throwing any exception)
I have a program that is running on a low powered computer that is writing out a com port via a RS232 USB to serial adapter. I noticed that occasionally I was not seeing responses to commands and I investigated with a logic analyzer and found that the commands I was calling to be written never were. On my more powerful laptop I never had any issues.
I wrote a little test application to see if the problem was my code or not, and it doesn't appear to be related to my code.
Here is the little test application I wrote. It just prints and see if it receives what it printed. For this test I used a USB to TTL and connected the TX to the RX and it has the same issue as my production application of not firing commands occasionally.
A rx issue would show the same in this test, but I watched the communication and it never failed due to a receive, only a transmit.
Of course neither write in the SerialPort or SerialStream class give an indication of success.
namespace SerialTest
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Com Name:");
            string comName = Console.ReadLine()!;

            Test test = new Test(comName);
            test.Run();
        }
    }
}

namespace SerialTest
{
    internal class Test
    {
        private int Errors = 0;
        private SerialService serialService;

        public Test(string comPort)
        {
            serialService = new SerialService(comPort);
        }

        public void Run()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                var command = CreateRandom(10);

                List<string> acceptedResponse = new List<string> { command };
                var success = serialService.SendAndWait(command, acceptedResponse);

                if (!success)
                {
                    Errors++;
                }

                UpdateScreen();

                Thread.Sleep(300);
            }
        }

        private string CreateRandom(int length)
        {
            // create a random string of characters

            Random random = new Random();
            const string chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";

            return new string(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, length)
              .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());
        }

        private void UpdateScreen()
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Errors: " + Errors);
        }
    }
}

namespace SerialTest
{
    public class SerialService
    {
        private SerialPort serialPort;
        private string inputBuffer = string.Empty;
        private int defaultTimeout = 2000;

        public SerialService(string portName)
        {
            serialPort = new SerialPort();

            serialPort.PortName = portName;
            serialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
            serialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
            serialPort.DataBits = 8;
            serialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(serialPort_DataReceived);

            serialPort.Open();
        }

        //This event fires anytime data is recieved from the serial port
        //It adds the data to the input buffer and appends it to the terminal of the form
        private void serialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string recievedData = serialPort.ReadExisting();

                inputBuffer += recievedData;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error reading from serial port: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void SPWrite(string command, int timeout)
        {
            serialPort.BaseStream.WriteTimeout = timeout;
            var bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(command);
            serialPort.BaseStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

            //serialPort.BaseStream.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length).Wait();

            serialPort.BaseStream.Flush();
        }

        public void SendCommand(string command)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(125);

            try
            {
                SPWrite(command, defaultTimeout);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error writing to serial port: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        public bool SendAndWait(string command, List<string> responses, int timeout = 300)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(125);

            try
            {
                SPWrite(command, timeout);

                var startTime = DateTime.Now;

                while (DateTime.Now.Subtract(startTime).TotalMilliseconds < timeout)
                {
                    if (responses.Any(x => inputBuffer.Contains(x)))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }

                Console.WriteLine($"Timeout waiting for response to command: {command}");

                return false;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error sending command: {command} to {serialPort.PortName}: {ex.Message} {ex.StackTrace}");

                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}

I also tried to see if I could use position to keep track of whether we had sent or not but the SerialStream class doesn't allow seeking.
As you can see I tried going one layer deeper into the serial ports base stream and had no luck.
Are there any solutions anyone can think of, or an alternative class that can be used that is functional on windows and linux?
Also does anyone know of documentation that actually shows how these classes work? I didn't have luck figuring it out by digging into the code of the SerialPort or SerialStream class.
Edit:
I tried looking at the Bytes to write and not moving out of the function unless that value was 0, interestingly that also did not fix the problem.
while (serialPort.BytesToWrite != 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for bytes to write");
    Thread.Sleep(1);
}

Edit 2:
This issue does seem to be localized to this lower powered pannel pc. I still feel like .NET should give me some kind of indication something has gone wrong, but I guess it could be at a lower windows level. But a raspberry pi 4 runs the application perfectly.
Here is good communication from MSI Laptop:

Here is good communication from raspberry pi:

Here is what a run from the Panel PC looks like:


Why do you need to sleep? Should not be necessary using async method.  Make sure you  target Core is you are running on both Windows and Linux.

There is nothing async here. The sleeps are there because on the fast computer I was occasionally too quick for the embedded processor I was talking to, so time was there to allow the embedded C to get ready to receive another command.

That will introduce funny bugs. If you really need to accomodate the slow target, then build that into your protocol.

None of that is the current issue. The issue is calling .Write and nothing going out the usb to serial... If I remove those delays in this test app, commands will still be lost, they are happening before anything is going on with the serial port, not during.

What is happening is you are not getting the entire response in one chunk.  TCP data can be received in multiple datagrams.  Adding a sleep is just a kludge to solve issue.  If you are sending ascii data than terminate each message with a known character like a return.  Then on receive end loop until you get the return.  Then update the screen.  When sending binary proceed each message with a byte count and then when receive read until you get all the characters by the count.

As I said the receive is not the issue. Using a logic analyzer on my RS232 serial port I can see that the data is never making it out the serial port. The SerialPort Class' .Write function is the culprit. It is moving on despite having never written. My issue has nothing to do with delays.
The delay is there because a microcontroller board that I am communicating with needs time in-between commands to make changes to its state and it is very slow in comparison to a windows computer, BUT I can see with the logic analyzer that the device in question is not getting the commands from the port.

Why not try the sample program on the Microsoft site as is, or modify it as necessary? Examples - SerialPort Class

You're probably at the mercy of the USB-to-Virtual-ComPort driver, provided by whatever converter you're using. You won't see it on the Pi because it has a hardware RS232 controller. I suggest trying out a USB converter with a different chip & driver (many of them share the same chip and repackage the same windows driver). Or maybe stick a Pi next to the panelpc and write an ethernet-to-serial converter app for the Pi, and do ethernet comms on Windows.

I actually used the same usb converter on all three of those tests. Which means the same driver on the msi laptop as the panel pc. Unless you're saying the usb converter on the pi would use that rs232 controller somehow?

Oh I thought you were using the pi's native UART. Either way, I'm not blaming the converter, but its windows driver. The only thing that sits between your own code (which seems okay) and the signal analyser are the converter and its driver. Which is why I'm suggesting trying to replace them than trying to catch an error that you may never see in your code

Gotcha, I'll give a different converting that uses a different chip and driver a go then.

No luck, used a different one that required a different driver and had the same issue.
